# popping a stack I made in C

Tags: c, stack

I am writing a stack struct and push/pop methods in C as an educational exercise(Not homework I just want something to do, although I wish I had homework this good) and I am stuck with a dilemma.

When I pop a node off the stack, should I return the value on the stack or on the heap?

If I return the value on the heap, if the program using the stack doesn't free() the memory then there will be a memory leak, but if I use the stack then there may be scope issues and the user(probably just me) of my stack implementation will have to deal with extra work.

Up till now I have been using the heap for everything to do with the stack struct and it's methods, and when I tried to put the popped data on the stack the data was corrupt when I tried to use it in a test program.

(It might be good to not here that the stack implementation is designed so the user of the stack can change the element size and thus push many different types to the stack and different sized strings as it handles the data as a void pointer).

My stack implementation looks like this(I am new-ish to C so this may be a bit messy):

```
#include "cstack.h"

struct node{
    struct node* child;
    struct node* parent;
    void* data;
    int has_child;
    unsigned long int elemsize;
};

struct cstack{
    struct node* root_node;
    struct node* last_node;
    unsigned long int elemsize;
    void (*push)(cstack*);              /*function pointers here incase it suits someones workflow, not that anyone will use my stack implementation*/
    void* (*pop)(cstack*, void* data);
};

void push(cstack* stack, void* data){
    struct node* currnode;
    int isroot = 0;

    if(stack->root_node == NULL){
        stack->last_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        stack->root_node = stack->last_node;
        stack->root_node->has_child = 0;
        stack->root_node->parent = NULL;
        stack->root_node->elemsize = stack->elemsize;
        isroot = 1;
    }

    currnode = stack->last_node;

     /*If they have added a node themselves, which is fine, it will cause undefined behaviour so let's make sure
       the node has no children, but if they have hacked it let's hope they set the correct flags >->*/

    while(currnode->has_child){
        currnode = currnode->child;
    }

    if(!isroot){
        currnode->has_child = 1;
        currnode->child = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        currnode->child->data = malloc(stack->elemsize);
        currnode->child->parent = currnode;
        currnode->child->elemsize = stack->elemsize;

        memcpy(currnode->child->data, data, stack->elemsize);

        stack->last_node = currnode->child;                            /*update the last node position of the stack*/
    }else{
        currnode->data = malloc(stack->elemsize);
        memcpy(currnode->data, data, stack->elemsize);
    }
}

void* pop(cstack* stack){
    void* rtrn;
    if(stack->root_node != NULL){
        struct node* currnode = stack->last_node;

        while(currnode->has_child){
            currnode = currnode->child;
        }

        /*This is where the variable to return get's set
          when I was using the stack my code was
          rtrn = &(*currnode->data)*/

        rtrn = malloc(currnode->elemsize);
        memcpy(rtrn, currnode->data, currnode->elemsize);

        if(currnode->parent != NULL){
            stack->last_node = currnode->parent;/*we're popping the top node so the last node in the stack should be the parent node of the current last node*/
            currnode = currnode->parent;        /*elevate to parent node*/
            currnode->has_child = 0;
            free(currnode->child->data);
            currnode->child->data = NULL;
            free(currnode->child);
            currnode->child = NULL;
        }else{                                  /*it's the root node*/
            free(currnode->data);
            currnode->data = NULL;
            free(currnode);
            stack->root_node = NULL;
            stack->last_node = NULL;
        }
    }else{
        rtrn = (void*)NULL;                    /*this cast is redundant because NULL should be a void pointer anyway, but if it isn't then we need to make sure it is*/
    }
    return rtrn;
}

void change_elem_size(cstack* stack, unsigned long int elemsize){
    stack->elemsize = elemsize;
}

cstack* new_stack(unsigned long int elemsize){
    cstack* rstack;
    rstack = (cstack*)malloc(sizeof(cstack));
    rstack->root_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    rstack->elemsize = elemsize;
    rstack->pop = pop;
    rstack->push = push;
    rstack->last_node = rstack->root_node;

    rstack->root_node->parent = NULL;
    rstack->root_node->has_child = 0;
    rstack->root_node->child = NULL;

    return rstack;
}
```

My other idea was let them pass in a pointer to a pre-allocated variable so they would know it was on the stack and increase it's size if it's necessary.

I hope you can help me, I'm not sure whether I should just go for the heap and hope I/people have enough common sense to free() the data.

Comment: I think there's redundant information in the `node` causing issues. If you are pushing an element onto the stack, it should be pushed behind `last_node`. But your code goes further and checks `has_child` for the `last_node`. If it's really the last node, why would it have a child? The last node, by definition, shouldn't? Perhaps I'm not catching the logic properly...

Comment: That is in case the user of the stack decides to go and push a node without calling the push function, which would cause unexpected behaviour, that is there so that if they decide to use their own push method the pop method will still work correctly on the actual end of the stack, so yes it is redundant but makes it more hack-accomodating.

Comment: Then in your `push`, within the `if (!isroot)` block, you should set `currnode->child->has_child = 0`. If the caller is going to violate the interface "contract" for the stack, then they could do a lot of horrible things to it besides push a node without calling `push`.

Comment: It is arguable this belongs on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) more than here.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: *When I pop a node off the stack, should I return the value on the stack or on the heap?* You can't return a value on the stack since, when the function returns, the stack for that function is de-allocated.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I don't know how I would go about returning it as just data when I don't know the type.

Comment: If you're worried about the caller having *the common sense to free the data* then have the user pass in the address of their own data and your `pop` can fill that in. Then the caller has to allocate it, not `pop`. `void* pop(cstack* stack, (some type)* data)`

Comment: Hmm, I see where you are coming from there. But I wanted to keep the node struct "hidden". It's also possible that I could create a function that returns the current node and then pop should just delete it then?

Comment: Just pass the address to hold the data, not the entire node.

Comment: OK, I decided to add a function to get the current last node, and pop will just get rid of the last node.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest following the Principal of Least Surprise.  In this case it should probably be symmetrical to how the object and its memory enter into the stack.  Important questions are: Who owns the object when? Who creates the object's memory in the first place?  I would also consider the expected performance aspects of a stack. Generally insertion (push) and removal (pop) of objects from the top of the stack is expected to be O(1).  How do your potential choices align with this?

Thinking more generically I would generally expect that if I have to obtain the memory for an object, and then 'insert' the object into some Data Structure, said structure would then become responsible for ownership of the object. If I were to pop the item, that simply removes the item from the Data Structure, with it no longer the owner, ownership returns to the caller.

Conversely, if I wasn't involved in the allocation of the memory for object in the first place and the DST did it for me, I would expect I wouldn't have to be involved in the destruction/de-allocation later.

You can obviously deviate from this, but for every deviation you'll need/want to provide documentation so that a user of YOUR structure knows what to expect, particular in that these will likely deviate from most others that they encounter.

Another consideration is that if you want to return anything other than a pointer to the original object you are also going to be spending time copying/reconstructing the object. This of course raises its own issues in terms of copy procedure and performance implications.  What happens when really complicated objects start coming in and out of your Data Structure.

Comment: Do you think it would be advisable to pass the top node to the user and allow them to get the data from that and then the pop to just remove that node?

Comment: You could but that usually isn't what `pop` does.  There's usually a seperate method to obtain the top element without releasing it. like peaking if you will.  And in that case they wouldn't use pop; they'd probably use a method for the stack object like `erase` or `remove` to explicitly decide how the item should be removed and or destroyed.  Even then its a little cloudy who is destroying the memory.  What if someone puts a pointer to an object into two different stacks?

Comment: Ahh, yes that's sort of what I was getting at, sorry I wasn't clear. I have now implemented a new function to get the data as a void pointer from the top node. I have implemented pop as I said even if it's not a common way. If someone put's a pointer to an object on 2 different stacks then it won't make a difference if it's erased on one because when the data is pushed to the stack the node copies the data using memcpy to it's own malloc'd void* using the elemsize field of the struct.

Comment: You've put yourself in a very odd position by cloning the `data` during the push back.  Strongly consider NOT cloning/copying the memory there, and simply recording the pointer.  Otherwise no one can actually put the same object into multiple 'stacks' of yours without wrapping them in some other object.  I.E. Any change to one of the objects or the original 'data' won't be reflected in the next now..

Comment: Hmm, maybe I could have 2 modes, clone and non-clone.
I think it may be useful for some users to clone the data and not useful to others, then again, maybe if they pass pointer pointers it will just copy the pointer?

Answer (score 0):

I like my pop function returning the removed element without freeing it as it lets more freedom to the person that will be using it.

But that's a matter of choice, you can do a pop function having a void prototype and you free the element inside too.